# How to manually start windows update

Tags: windows, windows-update

How can you manually begin Windows XP's Windows Update without entering to http://update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate with IE?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From command line, force detect with:

```
wuauclt /detectnow
```

To troubleshoot machines updating from my WSUS server.

I am not sure if it will apply to normal online updating but it is worth mentioning.

Troubleshoot update issues with this logfile:

```
%windir%\windowsupdate.log
```

If you are using Windows 10, Windows updates are logged with ETW (Event Tracing for Windows): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3036646

Comment: If my gut feeling is correct, this is like setting Windows Update to *automatic* and the run hour to *now*. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to manually begin the windows update procedure in XP is to restart it from the Control Panel:

- Control Panel -> System
- Go to 'Automatic Updates' tab
- Temporarily turn off updates: check 'Turn off Automatic Updates.' -> Apply
- Turn them back on: check 'Automatic' tab (or whichever option you normally use) -> Apply

This forces Automatic Updates to restart, and the result can be seen in the logfile

```
%windir%\WindowsUpdate.log
```

This is also a great way to restart AU downloads if they have been interrupted for some reason.